# Trigger enter event on Android keyboard Phonegap Application

Tags: android, cordova, keyboard

I'm new to Android Phonegap. I'm using Phonegap cordova 3.3.0 to develop phonegap application. But I don't know how to trigger "enter" event on Android keyboard.

For example: when I touch on Input field, the keyboard appear, and I want to submit the form when press "Enter/go" button. Please tell me how to do it, or give me the reference link?

Thanks very much!

[image: Android keyboard]

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
 if(e.which == 13) {
    alert('You pressed enter!');
 }
});
```